# Bar code Scanner not working in Acumatica Mobile Application

Tags: acumatica

`add field "FixedAssetScanField"{ special=BarCodeScan ForceType="String" }`Added above code in Acumatica mobile customization editor, i can able to scan the bar code in android mobile but the scanned value not assigning to the field. Value was disappears immediately after successful scan. Can any one please help me to scan the bar code and save properly.I have tried it for both existing acumatica description field and custom field added by me. I have taken string editable value.

Answer (score 0):

Review your field to the DAC field, it could be that the cache is not stored.